# Why WPF CommandBinding with one button is effecting the other button?

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

My following code is [Implementing a custom WPF Command](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/implementing-custom-commands/). I have bonded only the first button (titled Exit) with the `CommandBinding` so that when `Exit` button is clicked and `e.CanExecute` is true in `CommandBinding_CanExecute` event, the `CommandBinding_Executed` event closes the app. This scenario works fine with Exit button. But, when `btnTest` button - that is not bonded with any command - is clicked,  `CommandBinding_CanExecute` event also gets called. This can be tested by placing a breakpoint on the `btnTest_Click` event and noticing that after the code exits this event the cursor goes to `CommandBinding_CanExecute` event.

**Question**: Why the `btnTest` button is also calling `CommandBinding_CanExecute` event despite that fact that `CommandBinding` is used only on `Exit` button. What I may be missing here, and how can we fix the issue?

**Remarks** For brevity I have simplified the issue. But in real scenario `e.CanExecute` value in `CommandBinding_CanExecute` is set to true by calling a function that performs a long complex logic that returns true or false based on certain scenario for the Exit button. And I don't want that long logic to be performed when other buttons (e.g. `btnTest`) is clicked.

**MainWindow.Xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Exit" Command="local:CustomCommands.Exit">
                <Button.CommandBindings>
                    <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.Exit" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
                </Button.CommandBindings>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Click="btnTest_Click" Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.Xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Why this event is calling ExitCommand_CanExecute");
}

private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}

private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
}

public static class CustomCommands
{
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand Exit = new RoutedUICommand
    (
        "Exit",
        "Exit",
        typeof(CustomCommands),
        new InputGestureCollection()
        {
            new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think `btnTest` is calling `CommandBinding_CanExecute`? It doesn't.

The `CanExecute` method of the command is called by the `CommandManager` whenever it wants to know the current status of the command. You don't control when this happens. The framework does. It's not connected to the `btnTest`.

If you have some complex logic in `CanExecute`, you should consider creating a custom command class that implements the `ICommand` interface and raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event whenever you want the framework to refresh the status of the command by calling its `CanExecute` method. This way you can control when the command should be refreshed.

You could then bind the `Command` property of the `Button` to an instance of your custom command class. If you google for "DelegateCommand" or "RelayCommand", you should find a lot of examples. [This](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) blog post may be a good starting point.

Comment: This can be tested by placing a breakpoint on the btnTest_Click event and by pressing `F11` noticing that after the code exits  `btnTest_Click` event, the cursor goes to CommandBinding_CanExecute event.

Comment: Yes, because the `CommandManager` calls it then. Like I said, you don't control *when* it's called. But it will be called very frequently.

Comment: Huuuun!!! So I probably should use some other logic because I don't want my that function (mentioned in my remarks of the post)  to be called by the click event of other buttons.

Comment: Did you really read my answer? Then you should provide your own custom implementation of `ICommand`.

Comment: Sorry, I was on holiday break. I thought when we are doing resources/binding etc. we can do it on application level, windows level, and local level. E.g., for a button, using `<Button.Resources>.....</Button.Resources>`. I was curious as to why then `<Button.CommandBindings>` is not local to this specific button. And, if it has something to do with `CommandManager` then what is the use of  `<Button.CommandBindings>`. A reasoning behind the use of  `<Button.CommandBindings>` may help. I may be missing something here. Am I?

Answer (score 0):

Any interaction with the UI which is considered by the designers of wpf to be significant will indirectly initiate a check of all bound canexecute.
The idea being you changed something, did something or other. Best check if all these commands should still be enabled.

It's actually commandmanager.requerysuggested() that is invoked.
This doesn't directly invoke canexecute.
What it does is tells commands they should go check whether they can still be executed.
This isn't completely insane because whilst your button's command is invoking some code then there's a fair chance if the user clicks some other button then your viewmodel will be partly updated or in some indeterminate state,

You should never drive other logic using canexecute.

It is very common to add a bool IsBusy to a base viewmodel and check that to see if anything is doing stuff and you should not allow the user to do something else.

An extra check within commands on IsBusy is part of this pattern.